# SVN Repository data corruption

Tags: svn, corruption

We had a rapid shut down by mistake when our SVN server in the office was unplugged and it caused data corruption.

**update**

The last commit to this SVN server was last Thursday.  The power outage that caused data corruption happened on Friday.  If I understand correctly this happened because the data was not finished writing to the disk which caused the corruption.  How could it not be finished writing to the disk after over 24 hours?  Is it possible that wasn't how it got corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming is a linux you first need to do a fsck. 
You have two options:
- Create an empty file in / partition named `forcefsck`: `touch /forcefsck`
or
- Run `shutdown -Fr now` to force a fsck after reboot.

Usually, this can solve file corruption.

Any old backups available?

HTH

Comment: The server automatically attempted that with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What system do you run ?
What error do you have ?

check the official documentation:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html